# Problems starting zookeeper

Tags: java, runtime-error, apache-zookeeper

I face a strange problem while starting zookeeper. Everytime I start zookeeper, it is getting started but it is getting bound to the port as a process that I am able to restart it again. Following is my zoo.cfg file

```
    tickTime=2000
    initLimit=10
    syncLimit=5
    dataDir=/var/zookeeper
    clientPort=2181
```

Also when I try connecting and executing zoo keeper commands through my java file, I get the below error

```
15/07/20 12:27:46 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
15/07/20 12:27:46 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)
java.lang.RuntimeException: error in updating node :/testnode/test result : CONNECTION_LOSS
```

So can someone explain me why is it trying to re-connect and help me sort this error out ?

Answer (score 0):

This occurred because my java home was not exported correctly. It was pointed to the bin inside jdk directory which should not be the case. So after exporting java home to the root directory of jdk solved the issue